# UITabelView Won't Scroll At All

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UItableView at the bottom of a UIView and I have a button on top of the table that drags it up. After it is dragged up though, the table doesn't respond to any touch. Any support? I have tried bringing it to the front of the view. My table is created programmatically. I can see it perfectly and there are 30 cells.

[image]
[image]

```
songTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 440)];
[self.view addSubview:songTable];
songTable.dataSource = self;
songTable.delegate = self;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:songTable];
```

Comment: More code would probably help.

Comment: Does the table view extend beyond the bounds of its superview?  If so, it may not be receiving touch events.

Comment: I believe the problem has to do with the main UIViews size and that the UItable goes past the bounds but I cant figure out a solution that wont break my apps functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to your comment as an answer.

Looking at your application screenshots (nice UI by the way!) I'm inferring that the design consists of two views that slide vertically.  The issue with the table view scrolling lies in the fact that your table view is being added outside of the bounds of its superview and is therefore not receiving touch events.  Here's how I would setup the view hierarchy to fix this:

```
[self view]
    [container view]
        [current song album art view]
        [song playing view]
        [song controls view]
        [table view]
```

To achieve the sliding effect, you could just alter the y-origin of "container view" or also apply vertical transforms to it.  Just make "container view" have a height of 900 points or whatever the height of your elements totals up to, and you're set, since every subview is laid out within the bounds of its superview.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was coming along to the same solution.